# Create a modal popup welcome message in WordPress dashboard

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have been trying to use this code to create a modal popup that welcomes user in the WordPress dashboard when one logins with the following snippet at the functions.php or a plugin but it doesn't seem to load anything / even the thickbox.

Hope someone helps. Thanks.

```html
add_action('admin_init', 'open_modal');

  function open_modal(){
      $id = get_current_user_id();
      $user = get_userdata($id);
      if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles)){
  ?>

    <script>
      function call_to_open_modal(){
        //your code goes here...
      }

      call_to_open_modal();
    </script>

 <?php } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors in console? Try to echo your javascript inside the function :

```
add_action('admin_init', 'open_modal');

  function open_modal(){
      $id = get_current_user_id();
      $user = get_userdata($id);
      if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles)){
  echo 
    "<script>
      function call_to_open_modal(){
        //your code goes here...
      }

      call_to_open_modal();
    </script>";

 } }
```